# Removing duplicate values from two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
existing ["562fae5a626ca2e032947baa"]

new array [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
  { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ]

modified [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
  { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ]
```

I have an `existing` array and a `new` array, i want to `compare` the `existing` and the `new array` and remove the `duplicates`.

```
var existing = ["562fae5a626ca2e032947baa"];
var newArr = [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
      { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ];

newArr = newArr.filter(function(val){
    return existing.indexOf(val) == -1;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

When i try to print newArr, i still get the two objects?

```
modified [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
  { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ]
```

I want the modified array to have only.

```
modified [{ _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ]
```

Below is the fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ema6upg1/2/

Comment: You're trying to compare the simple string that's in `existing` to the *objects* that are in `newArr`.

Comment: Are those ids unique for existing?  If so, use an object and save yourself some complexity.

Answer (score 1):

```
 newArr.filter(function(val){
    return existing.indexOf(val._id) == -1;
})
```

is what you need, val is an object, you need to compare its _id

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that one array contains objects.

```
var existing = ["562fae5a626ca2e032947baa"];
var newArr = [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
  { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ];

newArr = newArr.filter(function(val){

    if(typeof val == "object") {
        return existing.indexOf(val._id) == -1;   
    }

    return existing.indexOf(val) == -1;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lookup for an object property is more efficient than iterating an array to find an id.  Consider:

```
var existing = {
  "562fae5a626ca2e032947baa": true
};
var newArr = [ { _id: '562fae5a626ca2e032947baa' },
  { _id: '562fae57626ca2e032947ba9' } ];

newArr.filter(function(val) {
  return existing[val._id] || false;
}
```